# React + Webpack - Illegal export declaration

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm pretty new to React and I'm experimenting with it using Webpack and ES6. I have written the below code which gives me an `illegal export declaration` error and I'm not entirely sure why...

```
class Header extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <div id="header">
                header
            </div>
        )

    }

}

export default Header;
```

The error from the CLI is:

```
throw new Error('Error transforming ' + filename + ' to JS: ' + e.toStri
            ^
Error: Error transforming /Users/leaky/Projects/CBP/public-api/docs/app/components/www/header/header.jsx to JS: Error: Parse Error: Line 13: Illegal export declaration
```

I have the babel loader configured in webpack like so:

```
{ test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/ },
```

Comment: What is the stack trace on the error? Do you have any other loaders?

Comment: That error message doesn't come from Babel, looks like it's a `jsx` error, do you have the jsx loader enabled?

Comment: Works fine here: https://babeljs.io/repl/. Needs more context.

Comment: @loganfsmyth i'm using babel-loader

Comment: We need more info, I asked about the stack trace and you haven't shown us yet. That is not a Babel error, it doesn't exist anywhere in the Babel codebase. We need more info the solve this question. You need to trim down your codebase to a solid reproducible case, and then we can help. What is your full webpack config? Is this the only file you are loading? What if you delete Babel-loader, does the error still happen?

Answer (score 0):

As @JMM and I answered in this question "[import syntax not working with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730033/import-syntax-not-working-with-webpack/35525285#35525285)",

1. you might need to use `babel` or `babel-loader` to enable `import`
2. make sure any other loader is NOT disrupting `babel-loader`

hope it would help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't actually import any js file other than the compiled one. Had that problem once after migrating from various files to a Webpack bundle, I was still referencing the old non-bundled files, and the ES6 Import declaration were failing because of that.