# ES2015 not compiled correctly

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, reactjs

I have this line in a `.jsx` file in my react project:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
```

However, this is not compiled correctly into a `.js` file:

```
Parse Error: Line 1: Illegal import declaration
```

I looked here [import syntax not working with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730033/import-syntax-not-working-with-webpack) and here http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#webpack.

So I added this to my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Also, I added this to my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" }
  ]
}
```

However, the error does not go away.

It seems to me that I am using babel and webpack correctly but I don't have much experience with them so I'm not sure what I could be missing.

Comment: You have a fairly lengthy toolchain. You need to isolate which piece is causing the failure. Because babel by itself parses that declaration just fine.

Comment: You have `test: /\.js$/` so Babel is not processing any of your `.jsx` files.

Comment: @JaredSmith I have no idea how to do that. any hints on where I may start? any tutorials to do something similar?

Comment: @octavian It's a regular expression. If you want it to locate JSX extensions, you need something like `test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,` That said, read up on the documentation.....

Comment: @lux it still doesn't work

Comment: `"presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]`

Comment: @octavian well, you've got a 'framework' that *completely* mediates DOM access (react), a JavaScript transformer (babel), and a module-loader (webpack). You are going to have to try to isolate those different things to see what's causing the failure. The very first thing I did was copy-paste your offending line into the online babel REPL to see if babel accepted it as legal syntax. Try using babel/webpack on a simple example without react. Try react/webpack without babel on an up-to-date chrome install. etc, etc.